# Iframe overflows parent constraints

Tags: html, css, iframe

How can I make this iframe not overflow its blue container but instead fill the blue containers width and height?

In the below snippet, the iframe sits below the blue container. It should sit inside the blue container and take up the remaining page width (100% - 400px) and page height.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px; /*For debugging only*/
}
#menu-cnt {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#iframe-cnt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#editor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-cnt"> </div>

<div id='iframe-cnt'>
  <iframe id="editor" src='https://www.google.com' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I need to use a combination of fixed and absolute positioning.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
}
#menu-cnt {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#iframe-cnt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#editor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-cnt"> </div>

<div id='iframe-cnt'>
  <iframe id="editor" src='https://www.google.com' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating a simple task:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  min-width: 1000px; 
}
#menu-cnt {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
#iframe-cnt {
  min-width:0;
  flex:1;
  background-color: blue;
}
#editor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-cnt"> </div>

<div id='iframe-cnt'>
  <iframe id="editor" src='https://www.google.com' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
```